# How can I diff multiple files in my git changes at once?

Tags: git, visual-studio, beyondcompare

I use BeyondCompare to diff files in my Visual Studio git change lists. Frequently I modify many files, and want to be able to open them all into BeyondCompare to view the diffs in a single operation.

Currently, I'm double-clicking files one at a time, which is rather tedious. I'd like to be able to select all of the changes at once (or just a subset) and trigger a BeyondCompare diff for each of them in in a single operation.

I'm able to do this from within Perforce, I'd like to mirror the same behavior when using git in Visual Studio.

I'm happy to use an extension if it's not natively supported in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't provide a method to open all diffs at once in separate Beyond Compare tabs.

As an alternative, you can launch a Folder Compare showing all the diffs.

To launch a Folder Compare from git at the command line, run:

```
git difftool --dir-diff
```